Nextjs in Github Page cannot load css, js
I try to build a web application using nextjs 14,
after following some documentation I still cannot figure out how to do it properly,
this is my next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export',
  trailingSlash: true,
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: 'https',
        hostname: 'github.com',
        pathname: '**',
      },
    ],
  },
};

I have problem loading the css and js that required in the web, it come in the folder named _next in the output folder but when called it in Github Page go to 404 page.
all the file required is in the folder call _next however it refuse to show, how to solve this?
Thank you.
Notes
Using this config, this working fine with Vercel, Netlify, Docker, only Github page that error
